# What could cause this random comparison behavior in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, comparison

I wrote this code on my website

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log([] > []);
}
```

and got this output

```
LOG: false 
LOG: true 
LOG: true 
LOG: false 
LOG: false 
LOG: false 
LOG: true 
LOG: false 
LOG: true 
LOG: false
```

The output changes every time I run it. Why is this strange behavior happening?

You can try it out for yourself on [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/peterolson/BQEhD/).

Comment: That's IE9's console? In Firebug, they're all `false`.

Comment: No.. In my firebug they are all different, it was updated today to version 1.10 I beleive.

Comment: Hmm. If I open a new tab in FF (13), go to jsFiddle, copy/paste, `Run`, they're all false. But your Fiddle, they are all mixed up?

Comment: But I am not copy pasting I am running his jsfiddle

Comment: @Dale - Open a new tab and copy/paste into the `command` window in Firebug. Always `false`.

Comment: Clever troll I must admit

Comment: I can't believe people are upvoting this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the jsFiddle, `Array.prototype.toString` has been overridden with the following...

```
function () {
    return Math.random();
}
```

Try it like this...

```
[].toString(); // 0.6317324512006824
```

Comment: Right, there has to be something in jsFiddle (where is that?), if I run it in Firebug's command window, `false` every time.

Comment: In the middle of the linked resource disguised as jQuery: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25059665/jquery-1.4.4.js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/peterolson/BQEhD/

Comment: What a fakeout. Nowhere was it disclosed in the question what the true situation was really.

Comment: oops i did not notice the linked resource. here is my -1 for the question :)

Comment: @naveen there is no reason for this, OP just wanted to have some fun i guess

Comment: @GNi33: funny why people takes so much effort. :)

Answer (score 5):

The external jQuery file you've included has the following code on line 4022:

```
(function(){
    Array.prototype.toString = function() {
        return Math.random();
    };
})();
```

...A rogue little IIFE that overrides Array#toString.

Where did you get this jQuery file from?